# Unable to create new references from existing array. How to do that without using loop?

Tags: java, arrays, reference

```
char[] c1 = new char[9];
// Inserted values in c1....      
char[] c2= c1.clone();
Arrays.sort(c1);
```

We only want to use sort on array `c1` and not on array `c2`.

But above step also sort array `c2` based on same references. How to sort `c1` and keep `c2` unsorted in this case?

Answer (score 3):

`c2` doesn't get sorted.

Run this program:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] c1 = new char[] {'a', 'c', 'b'};
        char[] c2 = c1.clone();
        Arrays.sort(c1);
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println(c2);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
abc
acb
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`System#arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-). It allows you to copy a subset of the array into another array, which could also be used to entirely clone an array.
Example:

```java
char[] c1 = new char[9];
// Inserted values in c1....      
char[] c2 = new char[9]
System.arraycopy(c1, 0, c2, 0, c1.length);
```

Comment: But you can also use `clone()` to clone an array. So why should the OP change the code from calling `clone()` to the more complicated use of `System.arraycopy(…)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] originalArray = {1,5,6,8,4,2};
int[] backup = Arrays.copyOf(originalArray, originalArray.length);
Arrays.sort(backup);
```

After the execution of the code above, backup becomes sorted and originalArray stays same.

Answer (score -1):

Use : [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(char%5B%5D,%20int)) or: [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)